# Cannot read property 'name' of null (react-admin)

Tags: react-admin

I have the most simple code possible to check `react-admin`:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import buildGraphQLProvider from "ra-data-graphql-simple";
import { Admin, Resource } from "react-admin";
import posts from "./routes/posts";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { dataProvider: null };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    buildGraphQLProvider({
      clientOptions: { uri: "https://countries.trevorblades.com" }
    })
      .then(dataProvider => this.setState({ dataProvider }))
      .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
  }

  render() {
    const { dataProvider } = this.state;

    if (!dataProvider) {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    }

    return (
      <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <Resource name="posts" {...posts} />
      </Admin>
    );

    //or, directly return <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} />

  }
}

export default App;
```

but I always get the same error in console: **Cannot read property 'name' of null**

My dependences are:

```
    "graphql": "14.6.0",
    "graphql-tag": "2.10.1",
    "ra-core": "3.1.4",
    "ra-data-graphql-simple": "3.1.4",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-admin": "3.2.0",
    "react-apollo": "3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
```

What I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The issue was that I was missing `Mutation` type in my graphql schema, therefore the check

```
type.name !== schema.mutationType.name
```

threw an error, because `schema.mutationType` was undefined

Make sure you have a `Mutation` type in your schema even if it's an empty one

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wanted to write?

```
<Resource name="posts" />
```

Have you read the docs?

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Resource.html

Comment: I have read the docs thousands of times. The error is the same with your code. It seems it's produced in the dataProvider creation and I don't know why.

Comment: Ok, now you've correct the syntax error. Maybe you should try the tutorial: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html

What is your  "./routes/posts" content?